# How to use Excel Code Name in VBA Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie and create most of my macros by recording, however I have run into an issue.
In this macro I need it to run the exact same way every time - but the sheets it references will be differently named (but always in the same order - so same Code Name).
I have tried all manner of fixes but I can't seem to get this right and end up with a 424 error.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-18],'Sheet2'!C7:C13,7,FALSE)"
```

Sheet2 will have a varied tab name

I have tried:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(B2,'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!H:N,7,FALSE)"
```

and

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-18],'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!C[-12]:C[-6],7,FALSE)"
```

I need the formula visible in the cell when individuals are looking at the file.

Comment: You can set the code name by editing the `(Name)` property of a worksheet module, so no, there's no correlation between the code name and the order (and users can easily change the order of worksheets). If you select your Sheet2 module in the project explorer (Ctrl+R) and then look at its properties (F4), what does the `(Name)` property (first one on top) say? That's what you should be using instead of `Sheet2`. Also, this being a run-time error instead of a compile-time error means you aren't specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of each module.

Comment: `'Sheet2'` in the all-string formula represents the user-editable `Name` of the worksheet. Looks like the `(Name)` property isn't `Sheet2`, and looks like there is no `Sheet2` object in scope either (hence the "object required" error when dereferencing the undeclared `Variant/Empty` value)

Comment: FWIW [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) has code inspections that can spare you a number of avoidable mistakes and beginner pitfalls. When you pull a worksheet from `ThisWorkbook` by name with a string literal (e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")`, there's an inspection that flags it and a quick-fix that can rewrite it to leverage the codename for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I described my scenario well. I have my macro saved in my personal workbook. Users will be opening different files - all named differently but the format of all the files is exactly the same. and you are correct in this instance the code name for the sheet I need to reference in all files is Sheet4. I changed the code to read as such and it's still erroring out. can you be a little more clear in your explanation of what needs to change in the code I posted? Like I said, I'm still pretty new at this. Thank you!

Comment: If you select your `Sheet2` worksheet module in the _Project Explorer_ toolwindow (press Ctrl+R in the VB Editor if it's not shown) and then look at its _Properties_ (press F4 to bring up the _Properties_ toolwinodw if it's not shown), what does the (Name) property (first one on top) say? That's what you should be using instead of `Sheet2`. Go ahead and change the `(Name)` to `ExampleSheet`: now `ExampleSheet` is a programmatic identifier you can use in code to refer to that worksheet, and `ExampleSheet.Name` gives you its "tab name".

Comment: Note: this works because the `Worksheet` module is a _class_ with a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True` (that's hidden though), so the name of the class is also the name of a free, global instance of that class that you can reference from anywhere in your project. Not all classes have that attribute set to `True`, but `UserForm` modules do, and with Rubberduck you could stick a `'@PredeclaredId` annotation comment at the top of your own custom class modules to synchronize the corresponding attribute.